# Text Size and Style of Toolbar Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I am developing application which have multi screen support. I have completed all remain layout as per device size but I am unable to increase Actionbar/Toolbar size for same. its looking small in 10inch tablet. How can I increase size of toolbar text ?

My Style XML is like below

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">

</style>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.FullScreen" parent="noActionBar">
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
<style name="noActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="OptionDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">

    <item name="colorAccent">#C5CAE9</item>
    <item name="android:background">#3F51B5</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverseDisableOnly</item>
</style>


<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="SelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#888888</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemBackground">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
</style>


<style name="HomeTabTextStyle" 
    parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab"> 
    <item name="android:textSize">35sp</item> 
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
    </style>

<!-- Action Bar Style -->
```

and my layout xml which including toolbar is like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/HomeTabTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

My Java Code is like below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    setTitle("My App Name");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toolbar is like any other layout; that means you can add elements inside it like this:

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_my_activity"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

This will change the title size of your toolbar title; as you wish.

I hope this helps you achieve your goal! Good luck.

**UPDATE**

If you want to manually set the activity title, you can set an id for the text view like this:

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/title_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="25sp"
      android:textColor="@color/colorText"
      android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
      android:text="@string/title_activity_my_activity"/>
```

Then like usual,

```
TextView title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
title.setText("New Title");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi ! Please look at my java code...how can i change it as per your answer ? because I have not used textview....Thanks

Comment: You can basically add this TextView to your Toolbar like I did above and have different sizes of text in each folder for different device sizes.

Comment: yeah...I understood it and Thanks for your help but actually I am asking what should I change in my java code for use this textview ? Please check my java code that I have added in question... Thanks again and sorry for my less knowledge :(

Comment: You do not need to change anything actually; unless you want to manually set the activity title; in which case, you can check my updated code above

Comment: Hi ! Got it :) Thanks sir :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that! Happy coding